# inconvertible types; can not cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'hk.ust.cse.omp107x.fragmentspractice'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Appreciate if anyone could help in this.

My aim here is to pass variables from an activity to fragment. 
I was trying to display the text of selected radio button (which is in the activity) in the textview(which is in the fragment displayed in the same activity.) 
I'm seeing the above stated error in line "BlankFragment bf = (BlankFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.blankfragment);".

My mainactivity.java file is as follows:

```
package hk.ust.cse.comp107x.fragmentspractice;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                /*RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                String string = rb.getText().toString();
                Log.d("demo", string);*/
                BlankFragment bf = (BlankFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.blankfragment);
                if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton) {
                    bf.changecolor(Color.RED);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                    bf.changecolor(Color.BLUE);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton3) {
                    bf.changecolor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton4) {
                    bf.changecolor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My fragment.java file is as follows:

```
package hk.ust.cse.comp107x.fragmentspractice;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    public void changecolor(int Color){
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.relative).setBackgroundColor(Color);
    }
}
```

My main_activity.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hk.ust.cse.comp107x.fragmentspractice.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
        android:text="@string/displaytextview" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/redvalue" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/bluevalue" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/greenvalue" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yellowvalue" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankfragment"
        android:name="hk.ust.cse.comp107x.fragmentspractice.BlankFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment.xml is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hk.ust.cse.comp107x.fragmentspractice.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: For support `Fragment`s, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Hey Thanks Mike, Searched for answer on this but Couldn't find the link you gave above before posting this question. 
Thanks once again!

Comment: No worries. It can be difficult to find one that applies to a specific situation for that particular error message. Cheers!